# Add a warning to all questions in [xul] and [firefox-addon-sdk]

Tags: discussion, tags

I have 206 answers in the [xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul) tag and 184 answers in the [firefox-addon-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-sdk) tag. Every now and then one of these answers gets upvoted, and I feel bad having sent someone down a dead end. Normally, each of these answers would need a huge warning:

> This answer is kept for historical reasons only. XUL and the Add-on SDK are obsolete technologies. Modern Firefox extensions are built with the [WebExtensions APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions), the information provided here is irrelevant.

Yet it isn’t practicable to add this warning manually on hundreds of answers (and never mind answers given by other people). So, is there maybe a way to add a deprecation note an entire tag automatically?

Comment: I do not see any reason for such a warning. People have various reasons for using old technologies. There's no cause for alarm just because they found one of your answers helpful.

Comment: @CodyGray: There is exactly zero use for these technologies today, the browsers supporting them don’t exist any more – nor do the add-on stores. I’m pretty sure that people upvoting these answers today don’t realize that.

Comment: What do you mean "don't exist"? Software doesn't stop existing. There are people and institutions who still use Internet Explorer.

Comment: Doesn't Waterfox or Pale Moon still use the old XUL based addons? There are probably more Firefox forks out there.